# Getting error when trying to use Winotify (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the python module [Winotify](https://github.com/versa-syahptr/winotify)
to create toast notifications, but I'm running into a problem that I can't make heads or tails out off.
The test script I'm trying to run is the following:

```py
from winotify import Notification

toast = Notification(app_id="windows app",
                     title="Winotify Test Toast",
                     msg="New Notification!")

toast.show()
```

But get the following error

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\01 Libraries\Documents\Tosh0kan Studios\Coding\MangaDex Feed Notifier\_toaster.pyw", line 8, in <module>
    toast.show()
  File "C:\Users\igor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\winotify\__init__.py", line 197, in show
    _run_ps(command=self.script)
  File "C:\Users\igor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\winotify\__init__.py", line 72, in _run_ps
    subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Users\igor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1022, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\igor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1491, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]  The system cannot find the file specified
```

I really have no clue what's going on, so the most I tried was uninstalling and reinstalling, installing it in an older version of Python I have (version 3.9), and it still has the same problem.

Does anyone have any idea of what's happening?

EDIT

As @Pignotto said below, Powershell wasn't on my PATH variable. Once I added it, it worked fine.

Comment: `winotify` uses PowerShell, try to check if you have it in PATH

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command if you have not installed winotify package

```
pip install winotify
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).